# continuity of monotone increasing function which is defined on all of R

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm aware that a monotone increasing function from an interval to R at most is discontinuous at countable set of points. I'd like to know whether it is true when the function is defined on all of R? and if it's not true, can you give me a counterexample?

Comment: Well, $\Bbb R$ is a countable union of intervals  (each of finite length) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same proof for an interval will work over the case $\mathbb{R}$ ...when ever $a$ is a point of discontinuity then $\lim_{x\to a+}f(x)- \lim_{x\to a-}f(x) >0$ then you will find a rational number $q_a$ in  between $\lim_{x\to a-}f(x)$ & $\lim_{x\to a+}f(x)$ and since f is increasing $q_x > q_y$ iff $x>y$...so you will get a proper injection from the set of discontinuity of $f$ and rationals...that'll force it a countable set.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the result is true for any interval, so it is true for the interval $[-n,n]$ for any given $n\in \mathbb{N}$.  We also know that the [countable union of countable sets is countable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Countable_Union_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable), so if $D_n$ is the set of (at most countable) discontinuities of your function from $[-n,n]$ to $\mathbb{R}$; then $D=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} D_n$ is countable and $D$ is the set of discontinuities for your function from $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} [-n,n]=\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.